# Row Formatting In Power BI

Tags: powerbi, formatting, powerbi-desktop

I am having a dataset of multiple products with it's average rating over the months.

I want to ask how can we do row formatting for example: If the rating of a product keeps on increasing, color it with green else if it's decreasing it should have red color.

I want all this to be done in **Power BI**.

Sample Data:

[image: Sample Data]

Answer (score 0):

With this format of the data, you will have to create a measure for each of the columns you want to colorize. Here are the measures (assuming `Table` is the name of your table):

```
June background = IF(SUM('Table'[June]) < SUM('Table'[May]), "RED", "GREEN")

July background = IF(SUM('Table'[July]) < SUM('Table'[June]), "RED", "GREEN")

August background = IF(SUM('Table'[August]) < SUM('Table'[July]), "RED", "GREEN")

September background = IF(SUM('Table'[September]) < SUM('Table'[August]), "RED", "GREEN")
```

Add a table visual to the report with the columns from your sample and for `June` to `September` repeat the following. Right click the column in the values pane and select `Conditional formatting` -> `Background color`:

[image]

This will open a window, where you can select how to determine the formatting and shall it apply it to values only, totals only or both. Select to format it by field value and choose the corresponding measure for the column, like this:

[image]

Repeat that for the rest of the columns to get this result:

[image]

For more information, take a look at [Use conditional formatting in tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-conditional-table-formatting) article.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I am very much new to PBI.
The columns that you have taken 'Table'[July]' here are not my actual columns.
I have taken a table visualization and I have a date column in my table and I have used that in visualization.
So how we will do it.
As May, June, July etc. are not my columns name how can I write
 IF(SUM('Table'[date]) < SUM('Table'[date]), "RED", "GREEN").

I hope you will understand.

Comment: The answer is based on the sample data provided by you. If it doesn't match the data in your model, you should ask again, but this time providing sample data in the correct format. [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) is a good place to start.